# Cannot connect to another computer over TCP

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am working on a project that transfers files over TCP. It is written in .NET 4.7. The program works while the client connects on the server that is on the same computer but when I send it to a friend and I try to connect it I get an error:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

Currently the program only sends some information about the file that will be copied and is nothing is encrypted as I cannot send even these information.

Here's the code for the server (Invoke is used because it is run on a separate thread):

```cs
    private void Server_Start()
    {


        try
        {
            // Set port on 13000
            int port = 13000;

            //Get the ip adress for the server
            String localIp;

            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                // Try connecting to Google public DNS and get the local endpoint as IP
                // If failed to connect set IP as local IP
                if (CheckForInternetConnection())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, 0))
                        {
                            socket.Connect("8.8.8.8", 65530);
                            IPEndPoint endPoint = socket.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
                            localIp = endPoint.Address.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        localIp = "127.0.0.1";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    localIp = "127.0.0.1";
                }
            }


            IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse(localIp);

            // Create listener and start listening 
            server = new TcpListener(IP, port);
            server.Start();

            // Buffer for data
            Byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
            String data = string.Empty;
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Log.Items.Add("Server started on ip: " + IP.ToString())));
            while (true)
            {

                // Accepting requests
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

                // Get the stream object
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                // Read length of file name
                byte[] nameLength = new byte[4];
                stream.Read(nameLength, 0, 4);
                int nameSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(nameLength, 0);

                // Read the name of file
                byte[] name = new byte[nameSize];
                stream.Read(name, 0, nameSize);
                String fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(name);

                // Read size of file
                byte[] fileSizeB = new byte[4];
                stream.Read(fileSizeB, 0, 4);
                int fileSize = BitConverter.ToInt32(fileSizeB, 0);

                // Read start signal
                byte[] startB = new byte[9+1];
                stream.Read(startB, 0, 9);
                String start = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(startB);

                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Log.Items.Add("Size of name: " + nameSize.ToString())));
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Log.Items.Add("Name of file: " + fileName)));
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Log.Items.Add("File size: " + fileSize.ToString())));
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Log.Items.Add("Start signal: " + start)));

                // Response to client
                byte[] message = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Testmessage");
                stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);
            }
            server.Stop();
            Log.Items.Add("Server started on ip: " + IP.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Log.Items.Add(e)));
        }

    }
```

And here is the code for the client:

```cs
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IPAddress iP = IPAddress.Parse(ConnectIp.Text);
        int port = 13000;
        int buffersize = 1024;

        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        NetworkStream netStream;

        // Try to connect to server
        try
        {
            client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(iP, port));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => Log.Items.Add(ex.Message)));
            return;
        }

        netStream = client.GetStream();

        String path = "D:\\testingEnv\\test1\\testing\\Matematika\\2017\\Školsko\\2017-SS-skolsko-B-1234-zad.pdf";

        String Filename = Path.GetFileName(path);

        // We wish to send some data in advance:
        // File name, file size, number of packets, send start and send end

        byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path);

        // First packet contains: name size, file name, file size and "sendStart" signal
        byte[] nameSize = BitConverter.GetBytes(Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(Filename)); // Int
        byte[] nameB = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Filename);
        byte[] fileSize = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);
        byte[] start = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("sendStart");

        // Last packet constains: "sendEnd" signal to stop reading netStream
        byte[] end = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("sendEnd");

        // Creating the first package: nameSize, fileName, fileSize and start signal
        byte[] FirstPackage = new byte[4 + nameB.Length + 4 + 9];
        nameSize.CopyTo(FirstPackage, 0);
        nameB.CopyTo(FirstPackage, 4);
        fileSize.CopyTo(FirstPackage, 4 + nameB.Length);
        start.CopyTo(FirstPackage, 4 + nameB.Length + 4);

        // Send the first pckage
        netStream.Write(FirstPackage, 0, FirstPackage.Length);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[30];

        // Read the response
        netStream.Read(buffer, 0, 11);

        netStream.Close();



        client.Close();
    }
```

A friend tried to port forward the port 13000 but it didn't work either. We even tried with the firewall being down but nothing. I searched on the internet but couldn't find any solutions to the problem.

One thing to note is that both functions are in the same application. I don't know if that is the cause of the problem.

Does anyone know how what is the problem here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you ensured that `localIp` isn't `127.0.0.1` when you create the `TcpListener`?

Comment: I assume you've checked that the IP your server's using is not 127.0.0.1... Then make sure that the port is really open. Try to connect from outside to that host:port with telnet or Putty when the server is running.

Comment: IP of the server gets written out in the application so I'm sure it isn't localhost. The port is open and telnet won't connect to it. It does connect to my computer which is on the network( different IP) as I mentioned in the comment bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to connect to your server with telnet ? "telnet localhost 13000" or from other computer with correct ip and address nbr ? Try that while debugging your server code. If telnet works, then client code has some problem..

Comment: I tried it but it won't connect to the other computer. It connects to the local network (not local host but the one my laptop is on). The application works if I connect to my computer on another IP which is connected to the same router but with wire. What would be the problem with the client code?

Comment: Ok, with that info I think the issue is not in the code itself. Seems like a network related issue instead. It works locally and within the same local network..you can try to check if your friends IP (the one the server code is using after its started) is visible from your machine. You can troubleshoot that with ping and tracert commands in command prompt window.

Comment: Both ping and tracert time out when using his IP. He found out that his router doesn't respond to ICMP protocol but tracert connects. We've tried both private and public ip adress but when I used public IP in the program to start the listener it throws an exception saying "The requested address is not valid in its context".

Comment: He found out that the ping request reach his router, it just doesn't respond to them.

Comment: Ok. I think there still might be something with the firewall. For ping command to work ICMP protocol should be allowed on firewall. You could also try to test tthis the other way abound, your machine being the server and your friend tries to connect from his machine...maybe the firewall allows outbound connections better

Comment: I feel stupid.... We fixed the issue. I was sharing the local IP adress instead of the public one. I don't know why I thought it would work... I learned something new today. Everything works as intended but now I have another question. How do I avoid having to open ports for connection to be possible. The idea of my application is to be p2p. I know there is a p2p library in .net but I don't understand it. How do I go about it? is WCF the answer or something else?

Comment: Well I think you still need tcp and open ports with p2p solution as well. For me about that you can check "Firewalls and ports" section in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/bb985792(v=msdn.10). Regarding the technology to be used, I'd suggest to do your own p2p solution first - for learning purposes. Then you can also research some already existing frameworks and pick one that suits best your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much on your help. I will do my best.